# Linking tables based on a numeric char value within a larger char field

Tags: sql-server-2008, char, inner-join

Escentially I would like to do the following:

```
select * from thistable
inner join thattable on thistable.invoicenumber = thattable.commentsandsuch
```

However, the "invoicenumber" field is contained within the "commentandsuch" starting at a character position that varies per record, so I can't join the tables with expressions like the following (where the "invoicenumber" is ALWAYS the last 5 characters of "commentsandsuch"):

```
right(rtrim(commentsandsuch), 5)
```

Is there a way I can join two tables where the char field value of one table is contained somewhere within the char field value of another table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

EDIT:

Here's some sample data:

```
invoicenumber:                   commentsandsuch:
012345                           Reg:  021 Inv:012345 Cus:1234    Br:AZ Stk:THISPARTNUMBER123
123456                           Reg:  1123 Inv:123456 Cus:4789    Br:BY Stk:ANOTHERPARTNUMBER5
234567                           Reg:  74 Inv:234567 Cus:5274    Br:HH Stk:WOOTONEMOREPART0
```

Comment: show some sample data in both the tables

Comment: I would suggest that you change your data model first. Pass the `CommentAndSuch` column through some regex functions to extract the invoice number into its own column. Searching a string within another for a join is very slow.

Comment: I added some sample data @NoDisplayName, hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be `Join on Like condition` should help you but, query may become non sargable

```
SELECT *
FROM   thistable
INNER JOIN thattable
ON thattable.commentsandsuch LIKE '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), thistable.invoicenumber) + '%'
```

Comment: I tried your example and it seems to be doing exactly what I want! Thanks for all your help @nodisplayname!